# WordPress Migration Error

Tags: wordpress, migration, blogs

I have recently migrated website from my GoDaddy Linux server to GoDaddy Windows server. Along with the website I also wanted to migrate the WordPress blog that I have associated with the website. I am not a web developer so I have done everything following tutorials in conjunction with GoDaddy support. I have come thus far to be putting the blog up on the new server and restore the database backed up from the old server. I think I am close to resolution of my problem except for one thing. When I visit the blog http://www.shivsharmaphotography.com/blog, it redirects me to http://shivsharmaphotography.com/clients/shivsharmaphotography/blog/ and you can visit the link to see the error. When I log in to the wp-admin I can see all my posts, etc. there. You can see from the link that the theme and bg are as what I set.

I have uploaded the .htaccess and the wp-config.php (replaced) files from the old blog to the new blog directory. It didn't work after or even before uploading/replacing.

Again, I am not a developer. Could someone help me please? I could be wrong, but being so close to resolving the problem I have a feeling that it's something very tiny that's going wrong. I have already spent over 48 hours trying to fix this...but no success.

If this helps in any way, here is what GoDaddy support said in the last e-mail:

"Your domain tries to resolve to [redirected link as mentioned above. I can't post more than 2 links] when you visit www.shivsharmaphotography.com/blog.  You have a redirect preventing site resolution.  Please update your scripting to remove this.  While we can assist with any technical issues that arise, we cannot assist with site development or coding.  I have provided you with a tutorial below that may help you with your issue."

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Cheers,
Ashish

EDIT:

I just discovered something very interesting. When I tried to visit the blog from the website, it worked! I check the URL, it showed - "shivsharmaphotography.com/blog/". I tried to go back to checking by typing out the address in the address bar and it did work with the " / " at the end, but not without. How do I make "shivsharmaphotography.com/blog" work?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is url problem. When you are migrating wordpress site from one server to another server, so its create url problem like http: //theoldserver to, for example, http: //thenewserver.com is problematic. 
So download file from this [site](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) and put this file, where blog files placed on server. Then do step, which define on this [url](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

This is very handy tool
[Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script" tool that's very handy](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) (make sure to read the instructions and have a backup of the db before using it).

Thanks